# Iterate through all cells in a column instead of checking all cells individually

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I have a simple list with labels and values in a Google Spreadsheet. Below, I have some fields in which I would like to get the value when writing the label.

[image]

For example, if I write `D` in a cell, I want the next cell to show `4`, the value corresponding to `D`.

This can of course be done with repetitive `IF`s inside `IF`s inside `IF`s... in cell `B8`, like this:

```
=IF(A8=A1;B1; IF(A8=A2;B2; IF(A8=A3;B3; IF(A8=A4;B4; IF(A8=A5;B5;0)))))
```

This simply checks row by row: If the written value matches the label of row 1, then show the value. If not, then perform a new `IF` command on the second row. Etc.

With many rows this is quite tedious. **Is it possible in Google Spreadsheets to simplify this a bit? For instance, can I in some way collect all cells in a column in one `IF` statement by doing `A1:A5` or something like that?** Something along the lines of:

```
=IF(A8=A1:A5;B1:B5;0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solve it by using simple `VLOOKUP`:

```
=VLOOKUP(A8, A1:B5, 2, 0)
```

[image: 0]